# Want 1st value in Standard edit Multi-Picklist.?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to get the first value of an standard multi-picklist.

```
String[] tmpString = opp.Project_Manager_s__c.split(';');
```

But its giving me random values.Please help me this.
I am just debugging tmpString[0]

Its giving me random values not the first value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have used opp.Project_Manager_s__c in that filed api there is __c is persent which means its a custom filed you have created.

if u have created the multislect pick list there are two check box while you are creating it.
1)
Sort values alphabetically, not in the order entered. Values will be displayed alphabetically everywhere
2) Use first value as default value

In this if u select the first checkbox it will automatically sort your values alphabetically.
If u select second onw it will select the first value as the default picklist value.

I think from this it does not throws any randm values . You can get the desired output.

[image]

Comment: No i am querying the value in Apex.like there are 5 values..user selects only 2 values..hai,abc..i want to get the "Hai" in my 0th index..but when i debug ..i am sometimes getting hai in my 0th index,sometimes 1st....I always want the value "hai" at the 0th index...

Answer (score 0):

In my tests, no matter what order I put the values into the Multi Select Picklist field, they come back out in the order they are defined in the field. 
[image: Picklist field definition]

So when I populate the field in the "wrong order", Salesforce "fixes" it:

```
list<Customer__c> custs = [SELECT Test_Picklist__c FROM Customer__c];

for (Customer__c cust : custs){
    cust.Test_Picklist__c = 'three;two;one';
}

update custs;

for (Customer__c cust : [SELECT Test_Picklist__c FROM Customer__c WHERE Test_Picklist__c != null])
    system.debug(cust);
```

gives this result:

[image: Debug Example]

So, in what order are the values defined in your multi select picklist? And have you ticked the box marked

> Sort values alphabetically, not in the order entered. Values will be
>   displayed alphabetically everywhere.

?